# Lottery with ordered draw - check my proof

Tags: probability, combinatorics, proof-verification

Let's assume that the order in which the numbers are drawn shall be considered. 
6 numbers will be drawn out of 30 numbers and each number can only be drawn once.

Calculate the probability that your lottery ticket has exactly 3 numbers which also appear on the winning ticket.

My approach:

Let be $\Omega:=\{(\omega_1, ..., \omega_6) \vert \omega_i \in \{1, ..., 30\}\}$ and $\vert \Omega \vert = { 30! \over 24!}$.

Let $B:=\{\omega \in \Omega \vert \omega \text{ contains 3 winning numbers}\}$. $\color{red}{\text{How do I rigorously write this down?}}$

Let $B^c$:= complement of $B$

Now I am not sure how to rigorously define $A$ the set of positive outcomes. It should contain three elements of $B$ and three elements of $B^c$ considering all possible permutations ot them.
$\color{red}{A:=(\{\omega_1, ...,\omega_6,)\vert \omega_i \in ~??\} }$.

Then the cardinality of $A$ should be: $\vert A\vert = {6! \over 3!}\cdot { 24! \over 3!}\cdot {6 \choose 3}$. Hence, $P(A)=\frac{{6! \over 3!}\cdot { 24! \over 3!}\cdot {6 \choose 3}}{30! \over 24!}\approx 0.068$

Is this correct? Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: Why does the order of selection matter?  It seems we are just interested in whether exactly three of the six numbers on the lottery ticket match the winning numbers in the lottery.

Comment: Minor note: you should decide carefully whether you want $\Omega$ to be the set of lottery numbers, or of possible lottery outcome 6-tuples.  Right now, you're defining it as the latter, but then in the definition of $B$ you write $\omega_i \in \Omega$ rather than $\omega_i \in \{1 \dots 30\}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, the exercise is simply set up this way. It has nothing to do with a normal lottery. It shall only test if I have understood the concepts of combinatorial modelling.

Comment: @Lynn, thanks for the remark. I have edited the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What we are interested in is whether exactly three of the six numbers on the lottery ticket match the winning numbers drawn in the lottery.

If there are exactly three matches, then the lottery ticket must contain exactly three of the six winning numbers and three of the other $24$ numbers.  Since six of the thirty numbers are winning numbers, the probability that this occurs is
$$\Pr(\text{exactly three matches}) = \frac{\dbinom{6}{3}\dbinom{24}{3}}{\dbinom{30}{6}}$$
which agrees with the answer you obtained.

A favorable outcome is any set of six numbers containing exactly three winning and three losing numbers.  If you wish to take the order of selection into account, favorable outcomes consist of ordered sextuples with three winning and three losing numbers.

Comment: I think my initial answer is wrong and so is yours. There are ${24! \over 21!}{6 \choose 3}$ ways to arrange three losing numbers. The remaining 3 slots are filled up with the winning numbers. The winning numbers are implicitly determined so you do not get more favorable outcomes. E.g. if (1,2,3,4,5,6) is the winning ticket a favourable outcome might consist of: (12,9,13,x,x,x) where the x's are placeholders for the winning numbers. But you can only fill up the x's with (4,5,6). Hence, it should be $P($exactly 3 winning numbers$)=\frac{{24! \over 21!}{6 \choose 3}}{30! \over 24!}$.

Comment: Are you saying that the order in which the numbers are placed on the lottery ticket must match the order in which the balls are drawn?  Your question merely states that exactly three numbers on the lottery ticket matches the balls that are drawn, which is not the same thing.

Comment: yes you are right I have misunderstood my original question. The answers are correct.